# Can I use article 'the' with a plural noun?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

according to this article [(Use 15)](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/advanced-articles.htm), it's against the rule to use an article 'the' before a plural countable noun (e.g. pictures, flowers, horses etc.)

*sentence:*
I've just sent you **the** picture**s**

In case if I can use it sometimes, please describe me the cases when I can use article 'the' with plural countable noun

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's not what it says. It says you shouldn't use articles when generalizing about uncountable nouns and you shouldn't use articles when generalizing about plural countable nouns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to make a general statement about something, and the noun is countable, you don't use the article:

> Horses have hooves.

The above means "All horses".

If you use the article, you're not referring to all horses, but to specific horses:

> The horses have been training in a simulated high altitude environment with low oxygen, to improve their lung capacity for the big race.

If you say:

> The horses have hooves.

someone might reply, "Of course they do!  *All* horses have hooves".

Comment: Yes, when we are talking about the whole generation of something we use *the*
(e.g., _The dog is a faithful animal_).